# Raspberry pi gpio reading file direction not working in c, except if program has been ran again and gpio pin not unexported

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio, sysfs

So I am trying to create a library for gpio control (using sysfs) in c, everything else has worked just fine up until I created the "*gpio_change_direction*" function, which is supposed to write to the direction file the wanted direction (for example "out"). The problem is that this doesn't work, because the "*fopen*" (included in the standard library) function returns null, but it does work the second time you run the program if you haven't unexported the gpio pin, it won't work, but if you have unexported the pin it won't. By the way I am using the Raspberry pi 3 b, but this program should work the same on any raspberry pi device, because it uses sysfs and not direct register control. And ofcourse I am using GNU/Linux for this, Rasbian to be precise.

So here is the code for the *gpio_change_direction* function:

```
uint8_t gpio_change_direction(uint8_t gpio, char *direction) {
    FILE *fdirection;

    char *direction_filename;

    direction_filename = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(GPIODIR) + GPIO_FILENAME_CHAR_SIZE + strlen("/direction")));

    strcpy(direction_filename, GPIODIR);
    strcat(direction_filename, "gpio");
    strcat(direction_filename, int_to_string(gpio)); 
    strcat(direction_filename, "/direction");

    fdirection = fopen(direction_filename, "w");
    puts("Hello");
    printf("fdirection: %p %d %s\n", fdirection, fdirection, direction_filename);

    if(fdirection == NULL) {
        puts("Helerror timelo!");
        return(FILE_ERROR);
    }

    fputs(direction, fdirection);

    fclose(fdirection);
    return(0);
}
```

The FILE_ERROR constant is defined in the *gpio_sysfs.h* header file, which I have created.

The main function (this isn't yet a real library, so it has a main file) I used to test the *gpio_change_direction* function:

```
int main(int argv, char *argc[]) {
    int i;
    char *d;

    d = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);

    gpio_export(24);
    gpio_read_direction(24, d);
    printf("direction: %s\n", d);

    gpio_change_direction(24, GPIO_OUT);

    gpio_read_direction(24, d);
    printf("direction: %s\n", d);

    gpio_unexport(24); //Works if this is removed and then the program is ran again

    return(0);
}
```

If the line with *gpio_unexport* is deleted then it works on the second time.

I have been changing the code hundreds of times, and tried many, many things, I would appreciate any help, and thank you in advance.

Here is a pastebin link for the libgpio_sysfs.c file: https://pastebin.com/sHaav6gY
And here is the gpio_sysfs.h file: https://pastebin.com/iwTr4Fjx

Comment: Can you try what would happen if you replace `gpio_export(24)` to writing `24` into the `/sys/class/gpio/export` file, and do similar thing with `gpio_unexport(24)`? If that works correctly, then it must be something bad in this library you use. Your defines look fishy: `#define EXPORTFILE GPIODIR"export"`, when you concatenate this way, you will get: `"/sys/class/gpio/""export"`.

Comment: Also, you don't close directory properly in `is_gpio_exported` function. When the matching file is found, you return from the function without calling `closedir(dir)`.

Comment: @itachi What do you mean by writing 24 into the /sys/class/gpio/export file? That is exacty what the *gpio_export* function does, I am pretty sure. And what do you think the *gpio_export* file currently does? You said "Can you try what would happen if you replace gpio_export(24) to writing 24..." but this leaves it unclear what does the function currently do.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I was saying about executing `echo 24 > /sys/class/gpio/export` directly, for example through the `system()` function. I have a feeling there's something wrong with your defines and `is_gpio_exported` function.